# Array Index out of Bounds exception from type casting

Tags: java, casting

(Ignore this question, nothing wrong with the code, I was very confused, however I have found it is the fault of a poorly made testing system).

This code runs fine, though it returns the original numbers, I want it to return the ASCII char equivalent.

```
public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.charArray.length; i++) { //Iterating over an array of bytes
        str = str + this.charArray[i];
    }
    return str;
}
```

This code causes a runtime error, casting the byte into a char causes an Array index out of bounds exception, I don't understand how casting the type changes anything about referencing the array index.

```
public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.charArray.length; i++) { //Iterating over an array of bytes
        str = str + (char) this.charArray[i];
    }
    return str;
}
```

Edit: I have found this error does not occur in an ide, but I still unfortunately get the issue mentioned below. The site I am solving the problem on is throwing this exception because of their testing system.

I have also visited some questions that explain how casting from a byte to a char can cause an issue where the result is instead a char that has the UTF value of a series of f's and then the byte's value, instead of a series of 0's and then the byte value, I found the explanations to be a bit lacking as to why this is.

Comment: You may want to check out the constructors for [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: What is `this.charArray`? A `char[]` or `byte[]`?

Comment: What does `this.charArray` look like? It appears to be poorly named, in any case.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: it is an array of bytes as mentioned in the comment, yes it is poorly named because it is for a poorly created problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the constructor `new String(byte[] byteArray,String byteEncoding)`?

where `byteArray` is charArray and `byteEncoding` is "UTF-8" in your case.

Answer (score -1):

You should use str.tocharArray.length